# Pivot table giving wrong count by 1

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a pivot table with column A which gives me a count of "Y's" from another worksheet. It either has a Y in the cell or it is left blank. For some reason the count is off by 1. I have another column B that has the correct count of Y's which is 55 while this column shows 56, any thoughts?

Note: Both column A and B should have the same count of 55. When I check the worksheet manually, they both have 55 Y's

Comment: Not to be rude with the obvious... but have you refreshed the Pivot Table recently?

Comment: Haha yes I have, it's actually a new table I made. I even tried adding and deleting "y" values in the original data sheet and refreshing the pivot table to see if it would fix itself, but no luck.

Comment: You can use the `Show Details` option to take a look at the underlying data with all the filters in place.  Maybe you can settle the issue that way?  Right click on the Pivot Table to get the `Show Details` menu.

Comment: I tried that a few times, there isn't anything out of place. Weird.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem a few days ago, went to all the blank cells and did "clear content".  Then refreshed the pivot table and it displayed the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to fix and/or eliminate this issue from happening in the first place ***(counting empty cells)*** is by right-clicking on the pivot table, click on ***"value field settings"*** and instead of clicking on ***"count" pick/click"*** count numbers".  Then right-click on the pivot table and click refresh.
This ensures that the pivot table counts cells that actually have a number in them and not merely a value that we can't see.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this similar issue (of **1 less count for one element**) and had to do some random pivot table counts of general items. Found two things:

1. Affects the count of the first element of a list.
2. It is because the the pivot table takes the first element of the list as the heading.(you can see it shows it as count of whatever the first element is).

**SOLUTION**
Add some heading above first element in the list and include it in the selection for the pivot table. The count should be correct after doing this.

(**This issue of 1 less count which is unnoticeable** for lists that you are not double checking counts by other methods can cause devastating issues and losses for engineering, monetary calculations etc.)

Answer (score 0):

In researching this for myself, I tried the blank row answer and that did work. However, someone on a different website suggested putting the data in a table and designating the first row as a header. Using this approach, the pivot table provided a correct distinct count without the requirement of adding a blank row. The table option is my preference as I don't have to filter out extraneous data from the pivot table that way.